# how to layout items evenly with overlap

Tags: html, css

I want to layout list items evenly across a vertical container. All items have the same height (the last one has padding).

Normally I would use flex, but here is the challenge: The container expands with a transition to its final height - which is exactly the size of all li items stacked up with no overlap. In other words, flex is not relevant since the container height will forever be <= height of each item * the number of items.

What I need, is for the items to always spread out evenly, overlapping each other while filling up the container (starting from a complete overlap until they finally are stacked as they would with no intervention).

Here is a sandbox link to the setup of the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-water-uln898?file=/index.html

Would appreciate your help!

```js
const expand = () => {
        document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].classList.add("expanded");
        lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
        
        
        for (let i = 1; i < lis.length; i++){
        lis[i].style.top= i*25 + "px"
        lis[i].classList.add("expand");   
        
        
        }
      };
```

```css
ul {
        padding: 0;
        border: 3px solid;
        height: calc(25px + 8px);
        transition: height 2s;
        position:relative;
      }

      ul.expanded {
        height: calc((25px * 3) + 8px);
        
      }

      li {
        list-style: none;
        height: 25px;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        width:100%
      }

      li:last-child {
        padding-bottom: 8px;
      }

      li.item1 {
        background: red;
        color: darkred;
        
      }

      li.item2 {
        background: green;
        color: darkgreen;
      }

      li.item3 {
        background: yellow;
        color: orange;
      }

      button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
      }
      
      li.expand{      
      transition:top 2s;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>

    
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="item1">
        item1
      </li>
      <li class="item2">
        item2
      </li>
      <li class="item3">
        item3
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button onClick="expand();">Click</button>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you asking to have 3 overlapping divs and then want to use a transition to get them to spread out and no longer overlap?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking. But I would like the transition to be on the container, if possible. without messing with different transforms for each elemet

Comment: In the real scenario, I don't know how many items I will have. So it would be great if there were just some CSS trick to change ONLY THE CONTAINER height and have the nested items lay themselves out evenly across automatically.

Comment: check the snippet.  I don't think it's possible to do this on just the container.

Comment: @DCR thank you for the help and the snippet. So basically you are saying that the only way is to explicitly move each item separately? No CSS property I could put on the container that would take care of that automatically?

Comment: I think that's correct although I'm not a css expert

Comment: I updated the snippet so you can now have as many li's as you want without changing or adding any css

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a bunch of wrappers. The list items are wrapped in an item with 0 height. Flex won't stack all the 0-height elements on top of each other unless its height is also 0 (because we must justify-content: space-between to distribute them when height is greater than 0), so the inner flex container has a height of 0 when closed, and the outer visible container (with the border) just adds a single items-worth of height to flex-container. The javascript is only for the demo.

This only works if every item has a known, static height. Transitioning height to `auto` is not easy by itself, let alone after you throw in some fancy overlapping.

```js
let fullHeight = true
const button = document.querySelector(".button")
const container = document.querySelector(".container-restraint")
button.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (fullHeight) container.className = "container-restraint closed"
  else container.className = "container-restraint"
  fullHeight = !fullHeight
})
```

```css
.list-item {
  height: 100px; /* ITEM-HEIGHT */
  width: 200px; /* ITEM-WIDTH */
}

.item-1 { background-color: #ff000066; }
.item-2 { background-color: #00ff0066; }
.item-3 { background-color: #0000ff66; }
.item-4 { background-color: #ffff0066; }

.container-restraint {
  height: 300px; /* ITEM-HEIGHT * (N_ITEMS - 1) */
  width: 200px; /* ITEM-WIDTH */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  transition: height 3s;
  overflow: visible;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container-restraint.closed {
  height: 0;
}

.expanding-container {
  width: max-content;
  border: 3px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 100px; /* ITEM_HEIGHT */
}

.wrapper {
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">transition</button>
<div class="expanding-container">
  <div class="container-restraint">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="list-item item-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="list-item item-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="list-item item-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="list-item item-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! This is great. There is just one thing I can't wrap my head around: It turns out I need to start from 0 height. Meaning, no items showing. 
When I try to achieve that by removing the padding-bottom from the outer container and setting the height to 400px on the inner container - I get this odd white spacing around the items, and I can't understand why....

Comment: I found that if I put a :not(:last-child) on the .wrapper rule it works. Not sure why though.

Comment: `:not(:last-child)` on the `.wrapper` rule would make the last item have a height, which is actually pretty genius, meaning that after the container goes below 100 px height, no movement will happen (which is the intended effect). You might be able to merge the `.expanding-container` and `.container-restraint` divs together if you use that rule as a substitute to the forced minimum size using padding.


Also, if you want to start expanding from a height from zero, I don't think you need you need the padding forced by the double containers. You can merge them for that reason too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position: absolute;` and jQuery animations to achieve the overlapping effect, like this:

```js
const expand = () => {
        document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].classList.add("expanded");
        $('li').each(function(index, li){
          $(li).animate({
            top: (index * 25) + 'px'
          }, 2000);
        });
      };
```

```css
ul {
        padding: 0;
        border: 3px solid;
        height: calc(25px + 8px);
        transition: height 2s;
        position: relative;
      }

      ul.expanded {
        height: calc((25px * 3) + 8px);
      }

      li {
        list-style: none;
        height: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
      }

      li:last-child {
        padding-bottom: 8px;
      }

      li.item1 {
        background: red;
        color: darkred;
      }

      li.item2 {
        background: green;
        color: darkgreen;
      }

      li.item3 {
        background: yellow;
        color: orange;
      }

      button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li class="item1">
        item1
      </li>
      <li class="item2">
        item2
      </li>
      <li class="item3">
        item3
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button onClick="expand();">Click</button>
```